# How to define Mongoose Schema for delete method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I am not able to delete items of a list of MongoDB.

Unfortunately, when `axios.delete` method is called in `ExpensesListItem.tsx`, the item of MongoDB list is not deleted (no error message gets printed to the console).

What is wrong with the code (maybe mongoose schema)?

ExpensesListItem.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { IconButton, ListItem, ListItemSecondaryAction, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
import axios from 'axios';
interface Props {
    expenseTitle: string;
    expenseAmount: string;
    currencySymbol: string;
    item: ExpenseAndAmountObject;
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

const ExpensesListItem: React.FC<Props> = (
    {
        expenseTitle,
        expenseAmount,
        currencySymbol,
        item,
        expenseAndAmountList,
        setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: Props) => {

        const DeleteListItem = (toBeDeletedItemId: any) => {
        setExpenseAndAmountList(expenseAndAmountList.filter(el => el._id !== toBeDeletedItemId));

        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', { data: { itemId: toBeDeletedItemId } ) 
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    return (
        <>
            <ListItem className="list-item">
                <ListItemText primary={expenseTitle} secondary={expenseAmount + currencySymbol} />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    <IconButton onClick={()=>DeleteListItem(item._id)} edge="end">
                        <DeleteIcon className="delete-btn" />
                    </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default ExpensesListItem;
```

routes.js

```
 router.delete('/expenseslist', (request, response) => {
    let itemId = request.body._id;
    ExpenseAndAmountTemplate.findByIdAndRemove(itemId, function(err){
        if(err){
            response.send("/Could not delete the item...");
        } else {
            response.send("/Expenses and amount item was deleted succesfully...");
        }
     });
 });
```

ExpenseAndAmountModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ExpenseAndAmountTemplate = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type:String,
        required:false
    },
    expenseTitle: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    expenseAmount: {
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ExpenseAndAmountData', ExpenseAndAmountTemplate);
```

Comment: Since you're passing an `itemId` parameter to `axios.delete`, for example `{ data: { itemId: toBeDeletedItemId }`, the `request.body` should be **`request.body.itemId`** instead of `request.body._id` within `routes.js`.

Comment: I've replaced it with `{ data: { _id: toBeDeletedItemId } }` at `ExpensesListItem.tsx`. However, the result is the same - when axios.delete method is called in `ExpensesListItem.tsx`, the item of MongoDB list is not deleted

Comment: Additionally I've removed `_id` from mongoose schema and now it works correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to delete with property "itemId" but you require request.body._id to delete the item. So instead of itemId, you need _id property on your request body.

```
  axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', { _id:toBeDeletedItemId } ) 
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

this should work if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Since replacing with `{ _id:toBeDeletedItemId }` I was getting `Argument of type '{ itemId: any; }` is not assignable to parameter of type 'AxiosRequestConfig'`, I've replaced it with { data: { _id: toBeDeletedItemId } }) and the result is the same - when axios.delete method is called in ExpensesListItem.tsx, the item of MongoDB list is not deleted

Comment: Additionally I've removed `_id` from mongoose schema and now it works correctly, thanks for your help